# VBA Help - paste in next row in range while in For

Tags: vba, excel

Having trouble pasting data found in For loop into the next available row of different range on the same sheet.  The range I'm trying to paste to is ("A295:A324").  I'm only using one sheet ("Printout") and never any others. He're's what I have so far

```
Sub CmpnyWkLoad_autofil()
        lr = 338    'last row
        lc = 69     'last column
        For r = 332 To lr  'start at row 332
        current = False
            For c = 60 To lc     'start at column BH
                If Cells(r, c).Value >= Range("V4").Value Then current = True: Exit For
             Next c
            If current Then Columns("A:AG").Rows(r).Copy
         Next r
End Sub
```

What I'm looping/reading is pre-filled dates in columns ("BH:BQ") and if they are after today's date, it copies the first 33 cols in same row and pastes it to the next available row in ("A295:A324") Then continues loop to end.  Any help finishing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I see you copy the row (though it's the entire row and not just `A:AG`, but I never see you paste it

Comment: All ten columns (BH:BQ) have dates? And you need to compare them all to todays date? Your question is quite unclear. Can you illustrate your data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

If my assumptions in the comment is correct you can try this:

```
Dim lr As Long, cel As Range

With Thisworkbook.Sheets("PrintOut")
    '~~> Check up to where your last row in BH is
    lr = .Range("BH" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '~~> you can also use lr = 338
    '~~> You said BH row starts at 332
    For i = 332 To lrow
        For Each cel In .Range("BH" & i, "BQ" & i)
            If cel.Value >= .Range("V4").Value Then
                .Range("A" & cel.Row, "AG" & cel.Row).Copy
                .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp) _
                .Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , , True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With
```

HTH